# How to change touchpad behaviour in chromium/firefox?

Tags: firefox, touchpad, chromium

I have ASUS laptop which has two finger scrolling, and it works out of the box.
When I am using firefox or chromium in kubuntu, middle click by external mouse on any of the link opens that link in new tab. Same behaviour is achieved if I tap with my two fingers on the touchpad. But in case of ubuntu if I tap anywhere with two fingers the dropdown menu appears. How should I change this behaviour of touchpad.

Bottomline: I want to open link in new tab with two finger tap on the hyperlink. How should I do that?

Comment: I used to have an eee pc and it had the same two fingers=middle click behavior, and it ran on ubuntu, but in my case there were no problems, tapping 2 fingers when the cursor was on a link would open that link in a new tab. I remember that the right button was simulated by tapping 3 fingers.

Answer (score 3):

@satuon: thanks... I forgot the touchpad is even capable of 3 finger tapping. It turns out they have interchanged the functionality of 2 and 3 finger tapping. Now the new tab opens when I click any link with 3 fingers.

Though I did not find how to change this behaviour.  I can mark this as solved coz I found alternative: )

Comment: Nice tip, been googling for this